# For loop - Understanding what happens inside the loop,Python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question, I read online but still not fully understood.

I have the next For loop and i would like to know how it works in detail.

```
matrix = [[]]
counter = 0
row = 5
col = 3
matrix = [[counter for i in range(row)] for j in range(col)]

for row in matrix:
    for elem in row:
        print(elem, end=' ')
print()
```

This first line in loop>>> "for row in matrix:" >>> Talking about the how many row i have but the second line >>> "for elem in row:" Talking about how many elements in row but Where is the use of the variable "col"?

I understand how the loop works in java or c++,  but here I do not understand completely, i would be happy to explain

Thank You.

Comment: `for row in matrix` is performing an unnecessarily confusing redefinition of the `row` variable; it's not connected to the earlier `row = 5`. (Also, the `matrix` initialization mixes up rows and columns.)

Comment: use http://www.pythontutor.com/ for understanding purpose

Answer (score 0):

In the second for loop you iterate over elements in the row which is excatly like iterate over columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is just like iterate matrix in row oriented way, for each row number of elements